# Throwing custom exception from completionhandler/block crashes the app in objective c

Tags: objective-c, exception, block, throw, completionhandler

I am trying to throw exception from my custom framework. It works well if it is thrown outside block.
But app crashes on [exception raise] if its within block.

How to create a completion handler/block with throws in objective C.

```
typedef void (^ServerResponse) (id responseObject, BOOL requestSuccess, NSError* error);


- (void)getData:(NSUInteger*)id response:(ServerResponse)response
{
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@data/%@“,ServerUrl,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)vid]];
…………..
………
if(statuscode == 200 && [response objectForKey:@“something”])
{
                    NSException* exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:@“Name” reason:@“Data id" userInfo:nil];
                    [exception raise];

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely that your block is getting called asynchronously. Thus, you have probably already exited your `@try`-`@catch` block by the time the exception is raised. You can confirm this by adding a `@finally` clause that logs some message, and you'll probably see it called before the exception is raised. But if the block is called synchronously, the exception will be successfully caught by the `@catch` block.

---

As an aside, if you want to report an error in a routine, you should pass `NSError` objects, not throw exceptions like you might in other languages. Exceptions are for programming errors you excise in the development phase, not to be used for control flow for situations that may arise naturally during routine use of the app.

See the [Exception Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000012i), which says:

> Important: You should reserve the use of exceptions for programming or unexpected runtime errors such as out-of-bounds collection access, attempts to mutate immutable objects, sending an invalid message, and losing the connection to the window server. You usually take care of these sorts of errors with exceptions when an application is being created rather than at runtime.